# Custom boundaries in asymptote 3D spherical graphs

Tags: 3d, asymptote

Ultimately, I'd like to draw something similar to

[image]

which I got from [this site](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/tag/higgs-discovery/) with asymptote. So far, I have (mainly using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228963/121799) as starting point)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
 usepackage("mathrsfs");
 import graph3;
 import solids;

 size(400); 
 currentprojection=orthographic(4,1,1);
 defaultrender.merge=true;

 defaultpen(0.5mm);
 pen darkgreen=rgb(0,138/255,122/255);

 draw(Label("$\phi_1$",1),(0,0,0)--(1.2,0,0),darkgreen,Arrow3);
 draw(Label("$\phi_2$",1),(0,0,0)--(0,1.2,0),darkgreen,Arrow3);
 draw(Label("$\mathscr{V}$",1),(0,0,0)--(0,0,0.3),darkgreen,Arrow3);

 //Mexican hat potential: call the radial coordinate r=t.x and the angle phi=t.y
 triple f(pair t) {return ((t.x)*cos(t.y), (t.x)*sin(t.y),
 -2*(t.x)*(t.x)+4*(t.x)*(t.x)*(t.x)*(t.x) );
 }

 surface s=surface(f,(-0.67,0.1),(0,2.032*pi),32,16,
          usplinetype=new splinetype[] {notaknot,notaknot,monotonic},
          vsplinetype=Spline);

 pen p=rgb(0,0,.7); 
 draw(s,rgb(.6,.6,1)+opacity(.7));
 path3 g=arc(O,1,90,-110,90,-70);
 transform3 t=shift(invert(3S,O));
 draw(Label("$\pi$",1),shift(-0.15*Z)*scale3(0.5)*g,blue,Arrow3);
 path3 h=arc(O,1,170,-120,150,-120,CCW);
 draw(Label("$\sigma$",1),shift(-0.5*cos(pi/6)*Y-0.5*sin(pi/6)*X+0.35*Z)*scale3(0.5)*h,red,Arrow3);
 draw(shift(-0.5*cos(pi/6)*Y-0.5*sin(pi/6)*X-0.15*Z)*scale3(0.1)*unitsphere,gray+opacity(.3)); 
\end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I did not manage to make the plot range in radial direction depend on the angle. (Another ugly point is that I need to plot the angle from 0 to `2.032*pi` rather than `2*pi` since otherwise there is a gap.) Any ideas how to accomplish this?

**EDIT**: Thanks to [O.G.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408723/121799), I was finally able to draw what I wanted.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
 usepackage("mathrsfs");
 import graph3;
 import solids;
 import interpolate;

 settings.outformat="pdf";


 size(500); 
 currentprojection=perspective(
 camera=(25.0851928432063,-30.3337528952473,19.3728775115443),
 up=Z,
 target=(-0.590622314050054,0.692357205025578,-0.627122488455679),
 zoom=1,
 autoadjust=false);

 defaultpen(0.5mm);
 pen darkgreen=rgb(0,138/255,122/255);

 draw(Label("$\phi_1$",1),(0,0,0)--(1.2,0,0),darkgreen,Arrow3);
 draw(Label("$\phi_2$",1),(0,0,0)--(0,1.2,0),darkgreen,Arrow3);
 draw(Label("$\mathscr{V}$",1),(0,0,0)--(0,0,0.6),darkgreen,Arrow3);

 real[] xpt={0,  0.2*pi , 0.5*pi , 0.7*pi, 0.9*pi ,  1*pi , 1.2*pi, 1.3*pi, 1.4*pi, 1.8*pi, 2*pi };
 real[] ypt={0.18, 0.15, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.22, 0.23, 0.2, 0.2, 0.18};
 fhorner si=fspline(xpt,ypt,monotonic);
 // try fhorner si=fspline(xpt,ypt,periodic);


 //Mexican hat potential: call the radial coordinate r=t.x and the angle phi=t.y
 triple f(pair t) {
 real ttx=.9*t.x+1.1*t.x*si(t.y);
 return ((ttx)*cos(t.y), (ttx)*sin(t.y),
 1*(-2*(ttx)*(ttx)+4*(ttx)*(ttx)*(ttx)*(ttx) ));
 }

 surface s=surface(f,(-0.67,0),(0.1,2.0*pi),32,16,
          usplinetype=new splinetype[] {notaknot,notaknot,monotonic},
          vsplinetype=Spline);
 pen p=rgb(0,0,.7); 
 draw(s,lightolive+white);
 path3 g=arc(O,1,90,-110,90,-70);
 transform3 t=shift(invert(3S,O));
 draw(Label("$\pi$",1,N),shift(-0.15*Z)*scale3(0.5)*g,blue,Arrow3);
 path3 h=arc(O,1,190,-120,210,-120,CCW);
 draw(Label("$\sigma$",1,N),shift(-0.5*cos(pi/6)*Y-0.5*sin(pi/6)*X+0.35*Z)*scale3(0.5)*h,red,Arrow3);
 draw(shift(-0.5*cos(pi/6)*Y-0.5*sin(pi/6)*X-0.15*Z)*scale3(0.1)*unitsphere,gray+opacity(.3)); 
\end{asy} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About the range from 0 to `2*pi` : from the documentation `surface(f, pair a, pair b,...)` the box (a,b) is considered and it means that the first variable varies from `a.x` to `b.x` while the second one varies from `a.y` to `b.y`. So it is sufficient replace `surface(f,(-0.67,0.1),(0,2.032*pi)` by `surface(f,(-0.67,0),(0.1,2*pi)`.

It is possible to add some angle function in the definition of `f`. To avoid a lot of test, a solution is to use `interpolate`, cubic spline (periodic or monotonic). Please find the code

```
 import graph3;
 import solids;
 import interpolate;
 size(400); 
 currentprojection=orthographic(4,1,1);
 defaultrender.merge=true;

 defaultpen(0.5mm);
 pen darkgreen=rgb(0,138/255,122/255);

 draw(Label("$\phi_1$",1),(0,0,0)--(1.2,0,0),darkgreen,Arrow3);
 draw(Label("$\phi_2$",1),(0,0,0)--(0,1.2,0),darkgreen,Arrow3);
 draw(Label("${V}$",1),(0,0,0)--(0,0,0.3),darkgreen,Arrow3);

 real[] xpt={0,  0.2*pi , 0.5*pi , 0.7*pi, 0.9*pi ,  1*pi , 1.2*pi, 1.3*pi, 1.4*pi, 1.8*pi, 2*pi };
 real[] ypt={0.1, 0.09,     0.09,  0.1,   0.01,  0.01 ,    0.02, 0.02 ,   .11   ,  .115, 0.1 };
 fhorner si=fspline(xpt,ypt,monotonic);
 // try fhorner si=fspline(xpt,ypt,periodic);

 //Mexican hat potential: call the radial coordinate r=t.x and the angle phi=t.y
 triple f(pair t) {
 real ttx=.9*t.x+1.1*t.x*si(t.y);
 return ((ttx)*cos(t.y), (ttx)*sin(t.y),
 1*(-2*(ttx)*(ttx)+4*(ttx)*(ttx)*(ttx)*(ttx) ));
 }

 surface s=surface(f,(-0.67,0),(0.1,2.0*pi),32,16,
          usplinetype=new splinetype[] {notaknot,notaknot,monotonic},
          vsplinetype=Spline);

 pen p=rgb(0,0,.7); 
 draw(s,rgb(.6,.6,1)+opacity(.7));
 path3 g=arc(O,1,90,-110,90,-70);
 transform3 t=shift(invert(3S,O));
 draw(Label("$\pi$",1),shift(-0.15*Z)*scale3(0.5)*g,blue,Arrow3);
 path3 h=arc(O,1,170,-120,150,-120,CCW);
 draw(Label("$\sigma$",1),shift(-0.5*cos(pi/6)*Y-0.5*sin(pi/6)*X+0.35*Z)*scale3(0.5)*h,red,Arrow3);
 draw(shift(-0.5*cos(pi/6)*Y-0.5*sin(pi/6)*X-0.15*Z)*scale3(0.1)*unitsphere,gray+opacity(.3));
```

and the result

[image]

You can easily modify the `xpt` and `ypt` values to find the best shape.
For `periodic` spline, do not forget to have periodic value.

O.G.

Comment: Great! But may I ask where the lower bound in `(0.1,2*pi)` comes from?

Comment: @marmot I add a comment. In view of your attempt, I transform the box (a,b) `(-0.67,0.1),(0,2.032*pi)` to `(-0.67,0),(0.1,2*pi)` so that the `x` variable varies from `-0.67` to `0.1` while the `y` variable varies from `0` to `2*pi`. Perhaps that `(-0.67,0),(0,2*pi)` should be ok...