# How to make a 3D arrow head in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to make a 3D arrowhead in latex. I used the below code but it only can achieve a 2D arrowhead. Is it possible to make 3D arrow head in latex?

This is my code

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,topaths, fit, backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,topaths, fit, backgrounds}
\definecolor{arrow_color}{rgb}{0.2, 1, 0.6}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rotate=-90,inner sep=0pt] at (1,0.0) {\tikz\draw[line width=2, -triangle 90,arrow_color, shorten >=-2mm, shorten <=0mm](0,0) ;};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The current output is

[image]

Comment: Do you also consider solutions on asymptote? (And the arrow does not get 3D if you load `\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,topaths, fit, backgrounds}` twice ;-)

Comment: Sorry, the line `\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,topaths, fit, backgrounds}` is redundant. Could you show me the link or the code to achieve 3D arrow head

Comment: What about this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267497/120578?

Comment: There are tons of examples on [this site](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/), and arrows are used in many examples on this site, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408694/121799), just search for "Arrows3". Those linked by @koleygr are gorgeous, but I'd like to argue that it will be very hard to get the same 3D feel as with asymptote with reasonable effort from Ti*k*Z (which I use for almost anything else).