# Input Values To Produce changing Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, key-value

I have a general question with a minimal example. Is it at all possible in Latex or Tikz to produce a field where an input value can be placed and once the enter key is pressed then a new output is produced? A simple Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \def\n{5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (\n,\n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces a square of length 5. Would it be possible to have a field where I can enter an input value of choice, press enter and then the new output?

Comment: You could put `\def\n{5}` in a separate file that you load with `\input` or just the data in a file. But you will still have to compile the file, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Marmot, in short a calculator type functionality is impossible?

Comment: I do not know if it is impossible but I am not aware of any method. There *are* amazing things one can do with pdf, e.g. you can produce 3d images with asymptote and change the view, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451803/121799. It is therefore conceivable that some expert finds a way. If you have one parameter that you wish to vary, you could use animate....

Comment: @MathScholar Well I think the output of LaTeX is a `.pdf` file not an `.exe` file so don't treat it as an `.exe` file.