clipping a plane by a box in asymptote
On page 99 of the Asymptote tutorial, there is a section header for cropping surfaces, but I cannot identify the relevant text.
I want to essentially "clip" a 3d surface, in this case by a rectangular prism.
The goal is to draw a plane which is bounded by a 3d box.
Here is an unbounded plane:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(1cm);
    import three;
    import graph3;

    triple normal = (1,2,3);
    triple point = (4,5,6);
    real d = (normal.x*point.x + normal.y*point.y + normal.z*point.z);

    triple plane(pair uv) {
        return (
            uv.x
            ,uv.y
            ,(d - normal.x*uv.x - normal.y*uv.y)/3
        );
    }

    surface theplane = surface(plane, (-2,-2) , (2,2));

    draw(theplane);
\end{asy}
\end{document}



Edit:
This is an approach I considered, but it is not smooth:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(1cm);
import three;
import graph3;

triple normal = (5,6,1);
triple point = (0,0,0);
real d = (normal.x*point.x + normal.y*point.y + normal.z*point.z);

triple plane(pair uv) {
    triple p = (
        uv.x,
        uv.y,
        (d - normal.x*uv.x - normal.y*uv.y)/3
    );
    // Clipping logic using inequalities
    if (p.x >= -2 && p.x <= 2 && p.y >= -2 && p.y <= 2 && p.z >= -2 && p.z <= 2) {
        return p;
    } else {
        // Return a point outside the visible range to avoid drawing
        return (point.x,point.y,point.z);
    }
}

surface theplane = surface(plane, (-2,-2) , (2,2));
draw(theplane);
\end{asy}
\end{document}



Alternatively, are there ways of restricting the output of the surface? I.e., similar to letting a<x<b, c<y<d, e<z<f.

I like the boolean idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227947/clipping-asymptote-3d-images?rq=1. There must be some way to restrict the output of the plane function
